# How can I print a column from 1 table with appropriately corresponding columns from another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a database with two tables: Products(Columns: Name, ProdID) , Sales (Prod ID, DateofSale).

I want to query a table with states the name and dateofsale of a product.  How would I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  This isn't a particularly advanced query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.Name, s.DateofSale
FROM Products p
JOIN Sales s ON s.[Prod ID] = p.ProdID
```

Comment: `[Prod ID]` is an invalid identifier in SQL